# android: how to query a key value pair efficiently

Tags: android, performance, key, keyvaluepair

I have about 3000 pairs of (key,value). They are fixed and will not be changed forever. In my app, there is a page that needs to make around 200 queries. For each query, they take the key and ask for value. Also, they are sequential. I have to finish query 1 to get the "value 1" so then I know the key for query 2 to get "value 2".

I tried to implement with SQLite. I measured the time and found this is very slow, it took around 600ms. I wonder if there is better way to implement it? For example, string array with 3000 size? or other hashmap? thanks for advice.

Edit: Forget to mention the size of key and value, size of key: 2char(unicode), value: 4~6char, in fact, it is similar to a lookup language dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the amount of data that has to be put in this container? E.g. 3000 pairs of five bytes: no issue, to keep that data in memory; however, 3000 pairs of 350 bytes: that's already about 1MB.

If you have a rather smaller amount of data you could think about using a static [SparseArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html) that gets initially filled by a SQL query or assignments in code. `SparseArray`'s are intended to be more efficient than `HashTable`'s.

If the key isn't an Integer a [HashTable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Hashtable.html) is still much faster than a SQL query.

If you have rather larger data sets, you could use a [LruCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html).

Comment: thanks for telling me about hashtable, i used hashtable and found it is less than 100ms. much improved! thanks